# Can somebody help me get out of this problem while installing ros-foxy-desktop?

Tags: apt, ros

```
$ sudo apt install ros-foxy-desktop python3-argcomplete
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-foxy-desktop : Depends: ros-foxy-composition but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-demo-nodes-cpp but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-demo-nodes-cpp-native but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-dummy-robot-bringup but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-joy but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-quality-of-service-demo-cpp but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-ros-base but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-rviz-default-plugins but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-rviz2 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-teleop-twist-joy but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-foxy-topic-monitor but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```